# Hibernation resume fail on linux kernel 4.9.0, Debian 9

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, fstab, initramfs, hibernate

I recently upgraded my kernel from 3.16.4 (Debian jessie) to 4.9.0 (Debian stretch).
Everything was fine, until I tried to "Hibernate" (suspend to disk).

When I use Hibernate option in LXDE, it appears to hibernate. I can hear the disk spindle ticking and writing data. But the problems appears when resuming from hibernation. The kernel successfully restores the image from swap, but then freezes and reboots, with all that work lost. I could not find answer anywhere on internet. The people are just solving some mistakes around not setting /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume or have set kernel paramters, or have wrong entry in /etc/fstab. I have these correct. Correct UUID in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume, correct fstab and not set resume kernel paramter.

- I moved the swap partition outside of the extended partition to primary. The UUID was saved and applied to the new swap.
- The system reaches "Restoring image 100%" and then "Suspending consoles", and then it powers off and boots normally, with all work lost.
- Tried clean install, but without luck.
- Happens only on i386 (32-bit x86), amd64 (64-bit x86) does not suffer.

Disk partition table layout:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                         
├─sda1 ext4   HDD      <ROOT-UUID> /
└─sda2 swap   HDD-SWAP <SW-UUID> [SWAP]
sr0
```

The sda2 was logical(resides-inside-extended) before the upgrade.

Fstab:

```
UUID=<ROOT-UUID> / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=<SW-UUID> none swap sw 0 0
```

/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

```
RESUME=UUID=<SW-UUID>
```

Kernel cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-686-pae root=UUID=<ROOT-UUID> ro quiet
```

System information:

```
Computer: Compaq CQ60-120ec
Swap Size: 3.5GiB
Processor: AMD Athlon X2 64 QL-66
GPU: Nvidia Geforce 8200M G
Memory: 2G DDR2 667MHz
Desktop Environment: LXDE
Debian Version: 9 (stretch)
Kernel version: 4.9.0-3
Graphics Driver: nvidia legacy 304xxx
```

(I know the processor is 64bit but it came with 32bit os originally, so I thought it was 32bit until I examined /proc/cpuinfo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to a conflict between hibernate and [kASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on [x86-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32). This can be solved by disabling kASLR with the **nokaslr** kernel boot option. [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) is not affected.

For Grub this can be done by editing /etc/default/grub and adding **nokaslr** to the boot options, e.g.:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet **nokaslr**"

Then run **update-grub** to update the configuration and **reboot** to give it a try.

<s>I had exactly the same issue and it seems that only the PAE kernel is affected by that issue. The same kernel without PAE works without issues.</s>

The workaround for me was to install linux-image-686 and uninstall linux-image-686-pae and linux-image-4.9.0-4-686-pae. The exact kernel version may change over time due to upgrades, but basically the currently running PAE kernel need to be replaced with a kernel without PAE.

It has actually nothing to do with PAE support of the CPU, as my CPU supports PAE according to /proc/cpuinfo. But PAE is anyway not of much use on old notebooks.

It has also nothing to do with kernel 4.9 PAE as the same issue happens with kernel 4.13 PAE from Debian backports.

Comment: This excellent answer would deserve much more ups, but I can give only one.

Comment: Yes thanks I thought this site is out of experts. (Un)Fortunately I figured that amd64 version runs without issue so I thought they stopped to maintain 686 version, but I didn't know that there is 686 version without PAE. I hope debian will fix it, otherwise people will complain.

Comment: Helped me with Debian 10 on x86_32

Answer (score 3):

Probably `/etc/uswsusp.conf` wants a changed entry for the 'resume device', if this is not used, myabe just try to grep your old UUID in all files in `/etc` to find a place wher change is needed. Also an `update-initramfs` would be necessary, I would say.

Comment: Nothing of this helped tried to install uswsusp and checking if the file was correct, but no luck. And no configuration files in /etc contain my old UUID.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. Reinstalling with the latest netinst iso, i.e. debian-9.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso sorted it out. Bug appears to have been fixed (at least for this architecture).

Comment: Yes I agree, it is fixed in amd64 (i.e x64) but the bug is still there in i386 (alias 686 or x86)

Answer (score 1):

I removed uswsusp and hibernation works again like a charm. BTW I think that it was already the case before Jessie when I was using nvidia driver, I tested using uswsusp and had to remove it to get hibernation working.

Comment: I don't have uswsusp installed on testing 32-bit computer, but hibernation still doesn't work.

Comment: Too bad. Do have you tried removing the nvidia driver and use the nouveau ?

Comment: Yes I tried completely clean Debian 9 installation (32 bit) but the issue is still there. It also happens on computer with intel graphics, so I think it has nothing to do with the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a swap partition (with correct size) and if you edit "/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume" with what "#blkid" result and i386 will not hibernate correct than it's a bug on Debians i386 4.9 kernel ! Update kernel to a version greater than 4.9 or roll back to 3.16 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the generic nature of this reply. I have seen similar questions all over the Web and decided to write one answer for all. I encountered the same problem as you upgrading Debian-Jessie on an Hp2510. I switched to  Ubuntu-desktop and found it there too. I subsequently did my testing on Ubuntu and the Hp2510 so it may not completely apply to your situation.

Some older computers updated with new Linux systems experience boot problems. They may not boot at all or they may take as long as three minutes to boot. Coincidentally, they either fail to hibernate or take so long to hibernate and dehibernate that the capability is useless. Often this is not because old computers are simply slow but because of a change introduced in the 4.8 Linux kernel, causing a problem with a very common Intel chipset, which includes svideo output. Beginning with this kernel, any computer with this chipset will experience boot problems unless the Linux command line argument `"video=SVIDEO-1:d"` is included in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. This will significantly shorten both 64-bit and 32-bit boot times but fixes hibernate problems only for 64-bit. No 32-bit system supports hibernate after this point. Further, the boot times for all 4.8 and 4.9 kernel versions are bad (except 4.8.rc1-7). This is finally resolved in 4.10. Kernels 4.8 and 4.9 should just be avoided (they are obsolete anyway).

If you want the fastest boot times, use a pre-4.8 kernel. I would use Ubuntu-desktop 15.04 with kernel updated to 4.7.10. This is the only way to get hibernation in a 32-system. The 64-bit system boots 7% slower than the 32-bit but it is still faster than any later version. If you want a currently supported 32-bit system and are willing to forego hibernation, use any that either are released or updated to a 4.10 or later kernel. Any 64-bit version works after 4.8 with the video fix but for best performance avoid 4.8 and 4.9.

To add the video fix do `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. After closing nano do `sudo update-grub`. Unless GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, which is inserted after GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, is blank, `"video=SVIDEO-1:d"` will not be the last Linux command line argument, which some people say is necessary. It actually can be anywhere.

You can always invoke hibernate with the pm-hibernate command in a terminal (or tty) but to have it an available GUI option you need to create or add to the policy file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/ com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` (obviously distro-specific) the following text:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
    Identity=unix-user:*
    Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
    ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
    Identity=unix-user:*
    Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
    ResultActive=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

At times the problem is not in the grub or UUID. This also happens when you are out of storage space. There will be no write space left thus resuming from hibernation will freeze.

When you get to that error, you can click on `alt+ f2/f3/f7` or `ctrl+alt+ f2/f3/f7` to open terminal. Login to your account or root using terminal.

Then run the command `sudo df -h` to check on storage space. In my case I had no space on my `/dev/sda1` so check on free space on the drives in the list.

If you are out of space, please try deleting some files to get some considerable amount of space.

After that you can click on `alt+f1` or `ctrl+alt+f1` and wait for the login gui to appear or type `reboot in the terminal to reboot`

Comment: Well, thanks for your attempt, but this issue has already been resolved. The issue is with 4.9.0 i386+PAE kernel. Later I discovered my PC was able to run 64bit software (although the PC was always running 32 bit from the day I got it), and 64 bit kernel resolved the issue.

Comment: Ok,  You are welcome.